# Rational/irrational connectedness in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose I have a line $y=1$. All points with rational coordinate x that are on this line are in set $X$. If $x$ is irrational, then only open interval from $(x,0)$ up to $(x,1)$ is in set $X$.

Question: is set $X$ connected?

It's clear to me that between any two intervals there is a rational number $y$ which "disconnects" them.

What happens if we zoom in on $1$ though? Suppose I have two rational points on the line. Is there a way to connect them?

Let's assume there is no and split the distance between them in two open sets. Considering it in one dimension (on the $y=1$ line) I would split it such that I exclude some irrational point on the line. BUT I could also go a little bit sideways?

Let's look at $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $(1,x \in \mathbb{Q}$). In any such neighborhood it's possible to find irrational points. But how does it help?
This is where my brain starts to hurt. There is no such thing as "next" irrational number, right?

Please avoid any argument about inherited sub-topologies, if possible, because we didn't discuss it yet in class. (But feel free to add it.)

Comment: It is not clear form your opening sentences what the set $X$ is. Can you give a better definition of that set?

Comment: @LeeMosher I hope this crude drawing illustrates it better: https://imgur.com/a/prldYCQ

Comment: It may be instructive to write this in set-theoretic notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of your subset $X$ of $\Bbb{R}^2$ is not very clear. I think you mean the following:
$$
X = \{ (x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 \mid (x \in \Bbb{Q} \land y = 1) \lor (x \not\in \Bbb{Q} \land 0 < y < 1)\}
$$
I.e., $X$ comprises the points $p_x = (x, 1)$ on the line $y = 1$ where  $x$ is rational, together with each open line segment $L_x$ with endpoints $(x, 0)$ and $(x, 1)$ where $x$ is irrational.

Here is a hint how to see that $X$ is connected: assume that $X \subseteq A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint open subsets of $\Bbb{R}^2$. We need to show that one of $A$ or $B$ is empty. For every irrational $x$, as $L_x$ is connected, either $L_x \subseteq A$ or $L_x \subseteq B$. Now consider the following subsets of $\Bbb{R}$:
\begin{align}
A_0 &= \{x \in \Bbb{Q} \mid p_x \in A\} \\
A_1 &= \{ x \not\in \Bbb{Q} \mid L_x \subseteq\ A\} \\
B_0 &= \{x \in \Bbb{Q} \mid p_x \in B\} \\
B_1 &= \{ x \not\in \Bbb{Q} \mid L_x \subseteq\ B\}
\end{align}
Now show that $C = A_0 \cup A_1$ and $D = B_0 \cup B_1$ are disjoint open subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ such that $\Bbb{R} = C \cup D$ and conclude that one of $C$ or $D$ is empty, implying that one of $A$ or $B$ is empty. (The tricky bit is showing that $C$ and $D$ are open, please post a comment if you need more help with that.)

Comment: Assume $p_x \in A$, then there exists an open interval around it and every open interval $L_x$ which intersects it (of which there are uncountably many) belongs to $A$ as well. This way we can show $C=A_0 \cup A_1$. Now $D$ is not empty since this would contradict the assumption (which we will contradict anyway at the later stage), so it surely must contain at least a point or an interval. Proceed with the same argument for $D$. I think it's quite clear from your, definitely better, choice of notation that they are disjoint "by definition".

Comment: It's probably clearer to separate out the arguments that each $x \in A_0$ has a neighbourhood in $C$ and that each $x \in A_1$ has a neighbourhood in $C$. But I think you are on the right lines.

Answer (score 0):

*Abuse of notation: Interval from $(x,0)$ to $(x,1)$ where $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ is identified as $(0,x)$. Point $(1,y)$ where $y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is identified as $(y)$.*

Assume $X$ isn't connected. Then it can be represented as disjoint union of two open sets
$$X=U\sqcup V$$
Fix $y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Then assume $(y)\in U$ wlog. Since $U$ is open, there exist countably many intervals $(0,x)$ that intersect a small neigborhood around $(y)$. Now define a projection
$$P:=\begin{cases} (1,y), &  (y) \\ (1,x), &  (0,x) \end{cases}$$
We can show that if $U$ is an open set then so is $P(U)$. Combine with $P(X)=P(U)\sqcup P(V)=(\mathbb{R},1)$ and we get a contradiction, since $(\mathbb{R},1)$ is definitely connected.

Comment: Your abuse of notation makes your answer (which I think may actually be correct) very hard to understand: the potential confusion between the use of $(v, w)$ for the open line segement between points $v, w$ in the plane and $(s, y)$ for the open interval between points $x, y$ on the real line is already bad enough. Then you make things worse. What on earth is $(\Bbb{R}, 1)$ supposed to mean?

Comment: @Rob Arthan, I'm deeply sorry for that but this is how I became accustomed to think about this problem. And as my question didn't seem to get a lot of traction I thought that posting any answer (even a rough sketch of it) is better than none. Maybe someone will find it useful.

Comment: Well done for a good try at answering your own question. I hadn't realised that the question and answer were both yours. Ad hoc notations often arise when we are trying to find solutions to problems, but when we write up those solutions we need to make a choice between converting to the standard notation or defining our new notations formally. (My experience is that using standard notation is usually best unless the new notations capture important reusvle abstractions.)